# Amazon Pinpoint MMS notifications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I'm wondering if anyone else is wrestling with AWS Pinpoint? Basically I have some long codes that people can text, which the messages then get forwarded on to SNS. And from SNS it goes to SQS where the messages are handled in the queue. Everything is working great, but I don't receive any notifications when a user includes a photo in the SMS message. I haven't been able to find any docs about it and long code "mms" is supported with twilio, so I figured amazon was the same.

I don't even actually need to process the image, but I need some sort of indicator so that I can respond to the user saying something along the lines of "Attachments aren't supported", etc....

Any thoughts? Thanks...

Comment: I've moved on. Switched over to Twilio.